# How to set image for Picture / IPicture for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcobjects, symbology, java, image

I am struggling with ESRI's Picture / IPicture Java documentation for ArcObjects 10.4.

I just need to grab the image file from my project's source (src) folder, and cast that as a Picture. 
Here's what I've tried:

```
File pictureFile = new File("myImage.bmp");
Picture pictureDisp = (Picture) pictureFile;
//  FAIL: java.io.File cannot be cast to com.esri.arcgis.support.ms.stdole.Picture
```

or

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("myImage.bmp"));
Picture pictureDisp = (Picture) image;
// FAIL: java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be cast to com.esri.arcgis.support.ms.stdole.Picture
```

I've tried the above scenarios with IPicture as well. 
I have no idea by what process on can set the Picture (or IPicture) in ArcObjects Java.

I can't use a file path, this project will be deployed as an add-in, and not all users will have access to the same file paths. I need the file embedded in my program. I just want my image file to be accessible via Picture or IPicture.

I've also tried creating via BmpPictureElement, with zero success.

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/sdk/10.0/Java_AO_ADF/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/support/ms/stdole/Picture.html

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/support/ms/stdole/IPicture.html#selectPicture(int,%20int[],%20int[])

http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/carto/BmpPictureElement.html

Comment: There is no such product as "ArcDesktop". There is a product known as "ArcGIS Desktop", but it includes both ArcMap/ArcCatalog/... and ArcGIS Pro.  Your documentation links are all from ArcObjects for Java (albeit long retired versions thereof). Do you mean that you are working with the "ArcObjects Java SDK"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# I use something like this:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap dotNetBmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"C:\Temp\MyBitmap.bmp");     
stdole.IPictureDisp pict = ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.COMSupport.OLE.GetIPictureDispFromBitmap(dotNetBmp );
```

Maybe it's in Java similar.

Comment: Alas. Of the 2 examples and 3 links in the question, plus many other fruitless searches, I couldn't find a functioning java equivalent. Always possible that I missed it, of course.

Comment: In C#, the current info is:  error CS0618 'OLE' is obsolete: The assembly containing this class is obsolete. Reference the ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Local assembly instead. What would that look like? I can't seem to figure out how to reference local assembly.